# Point of intersection of two curves

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I have been asked to find the angle between the curves

**$y=2^x\ln x$**

**$y=x^{2x}-1$**

But I'm having a tough time finding the point of intersection itself.

By trial and error, one could substitute 0,1,e....and find that 1 satisfies both the curves, but I think there might be more than one point of intersection.

My attempt to trace the graph was also futile.( I thought I could prove that the curves won't intersect again)

> in other words, find the possible points of intersection of the aforementioned curves

Comment: You have the single intersection $y(1)=0.$

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did indeed mention it, but I wanted to know whether there are other points of intersection

Answer (score 1):

Considering the function
$$f(x)=2^x\log(x)-(x^{2x}-1)$$
it cancels at $x=1$.

At this point, the first derivative also cancels  and the second derivative test reveals that this is a maximum $\big(f''(1)=-8+4\log(2)<0\big)$

Comment: Oh great! That answers everything. However, we must admit that we got lucky here, as we got 1 to be satisfying the function as well as it's derivative. But for say, I didn't know that 1 satisfies the equation. How on Earth am I going to solve that insane derivative equation?

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Hey! I've got another doubt! We found that it is the local max, how are we going to prove that there isn't any other?

Comment: Or in other words, is 1 the only critical point?